# text inside button not centered

Tags: html, css

Here I'm creating a button but for some odd reason the text is a little off and isn't centered even though I have used `display: block;` and `text-align: center;` inside my css file.

Line 30 is where my button starts here is my html and custom css code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Proto X Media - Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bg1">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img class="lgsize" src="logo.gif" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">


        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="pushdown">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <span class="text-center title">Proto X Media</span>
          <p class="text-center subtext">Professional Media Production & Hardware Consultation.</p>
          <div class="buttonpad">
          <div class="button">
            <span>Explore</span>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

And here is my css on line 39 is where the code for my button is

```css
.title {
  font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 500%;
  color: 373d44#;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.bg1 {
  background-image: url("bg2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.lgsize {
  width: 120px;
  height: 110px;
}
.pushdown {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 250px;
}
.menu {
  font-size: 100%
  font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
}
a {
  color:inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.subtext {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
}
.button {
  width: 82.61px;
  height: 37.65px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: 700px;
  box-shadow: 0px .2em 0px 0px #ebebeb;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: center;
  border: none;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
}
.buttonpad {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Thank you very much ! Also if you haven't noticed I'm using Bootstrap for my grid.

Comment: Seems centered for me when I run it? Can you provide a screenshot of how it looks for you? http://www.bootply.com/hmuIAuBVsj

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to use a div element as a button? You shouldn't be doing that..

Answer (score 5):

For centering horizontal, change your markup to this and you should be fine

```
<div class="button"><span>Explore</span></div>
```

When breaking line using an inline element, that line break cause a white space at the end pushing the text slightly to the left

For centering vertical, use line height, like this

```
.button {
  width: 82.61px;
  height: 37.65px;
  line-height: 37.65px;              /*  added property  */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: 700px;
  box-shadow: 0px .2em 0px 0px #ebebeb;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: center;
  border: none;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use padding like this;

```
 padding: 6px 12px;
```

OR

```
.button{
  cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple fix is to use line-height as the height of the containing div, as in this jsfiddle :

```
.button span
{
  display: block;
  line-height: 37px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/az2vs6y3/1/

Or you could also use negative margin and absolute positionning, but it would be slightly less flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using div as button, use html button for hyperlink and css looks fine

```
<input type="submit" value="Explore">
```